# how do I ask "are you Jason?" on the phone?

Tags: conversation

very simple question but I can't find the answer directly on google search.

1. Is this Jason?
2. Am I talking to Jason?
3. Are you happen to be Jason?

Comment: Nowadays, what with mobile and smartphones being ubiquitous, the problem of not knowing the speaker's  identity has almost become a thing of the past.

Comment: Is this a homeowrk question by any chance? I have nothing against homework question per se, but if it is, could you please explain the task in more detail? If this is a problem that you face with English native speakers, all of your suggestions will be understood but **only the second question is grammatical** (2. Am I talking to Jason?), and probably the best solution.

Comment: By the way your title also provides a fourth option, which should be included in the body.

Comment: @Mari-Lou not necessarily (re not knowing who is speaking). If you are phoning a business or there is an unfamiliar voice when calling an individual, it would warrant asking.

Comment: Have you seen our [Interpersonal stack](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: It's not a homework but I just ask on the phone that are you somebody? I want to be more polite so what is the best way to ask the person I am talking to ?

Comment: @marcellothearcane if this is a business context then asking if it is Jason speaking would be too informal. I also said in the comment "the problem of not knowing the speaker's identity **has almost** become a thing of the past". We all know that landline communication still exist but its demise is inevitable. Jassica in order to communicate with a user you need to use **@** followed by their **username**. I wish the site would provide this information to newcomers. Not your fault at all.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I do, to some of the customers I deal with :)

Comment: Mari, yeap please

Comment: Or you could ask "May I speak to Jason please?". BTW 3 should be either "Do you happen to be Jason?" or "Are you Jason?"

Comment: @Mari-LouA I’m surprised to hear you say (er, see you write) that – 1 is perfectly grammatical to me and the one I would always use if asking for confirmation of whom I’m speaking to on the phone. What makes you say “Is this Jason?” is ungrammatical?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  Yeah, you're right sorry about that. I was thinking along the lines of  "Is *that* [you] Jason?" and "Is that Jason [speaking]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends rather on how close you are to Jason.

If you are calling someone who is not known to you (for example you are calling a business contact) you would need something formal and polite, using full names and full sentences.

> Hello
>   Hello, this is Jassica Smith and I'm calling on behalf of Big Corp.  Am I speaking to Mr Jason Jones?

If Jason is a colleague or friend you can be more casual

> Hello
>   Hello, this is Jassica. Is that Jason?

With a friend you can be even briefer with rising intonation on the word Jason to indicate a question:

> Hello
>   Hello, Jason? It's Jassica...

If you think the person is not Jason (for example if a woman answers the phone)

> ... Is Jason there?
>
> ... Can I speak to Jason please.

Comment: This whole problem would disappear if it became standard in English=speaking countries to announce your name when answering the telephone and when introducing yourself at the outset of a phone call you make. I was taught, some years ago, that in Germany one's opening words when making a call should be 'Hier spricht [your name]'. It would save a lot of trouble. Just a comment.

Comment: It used to be considered the 'done thing' to give your name or number when answering, but with the growth of nuisance calls this is no longer recommended to holders of private landlines.